# Error al crear una función catalogar() en Herencia en Python

Tags: python

He empezado hace poco con POO en Python y haciendo uno de los ejercicios que tengo me encuentro con un problema.El ejercicio (herencia) pide crear una serie de clases con unos atributos designados, así como instancias de cada clase (4 en total: Coche;Camioneta;Bicicleta y Motocicleta) y meter estas 4 instancias en una lista(listaVehiculos)
En una de las preguntas pide crear una función catalogar(),que recorra la lista y muestre por pantalla a que clase pertenece la instancia y sus atributos.
El bucle que escribo se ejecuta pero siempre acaba en el else, y no encuentro donde puedo tener el error.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

```py
class Vehiculo():
    """Esta clase la usaremos para crear las clases posteriores que nos pide el ejercicio.
    
    args
    - color
    - ruedas
    """
    color = ""
    ruedas = ""
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        
    def __str__(self):
        return """ < {} >
        > COLOR: {}
        > RUEDAS: {}
        """.format(type(self).__name__,self.color,self.ruedas)
        
class Coche(Vehiculo):
    """Clase que hereda directamente de 'Vehiculo' e incluye nuevos atributos.
    
    args
    - color
    - ruedas
    - velocidad
    - cilindrada
    """
    velocidad = ""
    cilindrada = ""
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
    
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        > VELOCIDAD: {}
        > CILINDRADA: {}
        """.format(self.velocidad,
                   self.cilindrada)

class Camioneta(Coche):
    """Subclase que hereda de la clase padre 'Coche'.Esta clase, ademas de incluir los atributos de
       las clases anteriores,obtinene un nuevo atributo que indica la instancia va cargada o no.
       
       args
       - color
       - ruedas
       - velocidad
       - cilindrada
       - carga
    """
    carga = False
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada,carga = False):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada)
        self.carga = carga
        
    def vaCargada(self):
        if self.carga == False:
            print("La camioneta no va cargada.")
        else:
            print("La camioneta va cargada.")
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.carga == True:
            return super().__str__() + """
            > CARGA: Camioneta cargada
            """
        else:
            return super().__str__() + """
        > CARGA: Camioneta vacia
            """

class Bicicleta(Vehiculo):
    """Clase que hereda directamente de 'Vehiculo',e incorpora un nuevo atributo aparte de
       los dos atributos iniciales.
       
       args
       - color
       - ruedas
       - tipo
       """
    tipo = ""
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,tipo):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas)
        self.tipo = tipo
    
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        > TIPO: {}
        """.format(self.tipo)

class Motocicleta(Bicicleta):
    """Subclase que hereda directamente de la clase padre 'Bicicleta', tomando sus atributos
       e incorporando dos nuevos
       
       args
       - color
       - ruedas
       - tipo
       - velocidad
       - cilindrada
       """
    velocidad = ""
    cilindrada = ""
    
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,tipo,velocidad,cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas,tipo)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
        
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        > VELOCIDAD: {}
        > CILINDRADA: {}
        """.format(self.velocidad,
                   self.cilindrada)
    
def catalogar(lista):
    for l in lista:
        if type(l).__name__ == Coche:
            print("""
            > {}  ----> {}
                        {}
                        {}
                        {}
        """.format(type(l).__name__,
                   l.color,
                   l.ruedas,
                   l.velocidad,
                   l.cilindrada))
        elif type(l).__name__ == Camioneta:
            print("""
            > {}  ----> {}
                        {}
                        {}
                        {}
                        {}
        """.format(type(l).__name__,
                   l.color,
                   l.ruedas,
                   l.velocidad,
                   l.cilindrada,
                   l.carga))
        elif type(l).__name__ == Bicicleta:
            print("""
            > {}  ----> {}
                        {}
                        {}
            """.format(type(l).__name__,
                       l.color,
                       l.ruedas,
                       l.tipo))
        elif type(l).__name__ == Motocicleta:
            print("""
            >{}  ----> {}
                       {}
                       {}
                       {}
                       {}
            """.format(type(l).__name__,
                       l.color,
                       l.ruedas,
                       l.tipo,
                       l.velocidad,
                       l.cilindrada))
        else: 
            print("Error al mostrar el catalogo.")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    coche1 = Coche(color = "Blanco",ruedas = 4,velocidad = 260,cilindrada = 200)
    camioneta1 = Camioneta(color = "Marron",ruedas = 4,velocidad = 200,cilindrada = 160,carga = False)
    bicicleta1 = Bicicleta(color = "Azul",ruedas = 2,tipo = "BMX")
    motocicleta1 = Motocicleta(color = "Negro",ruedas = 2,tipo = "carreras",velocidad = 300,cilindrada = 280
    listaVehiculos = [coche1,camioneta1,bicicleta1,motocicleta1]
    catalogar(listaVehiculos)
```

Comment: Lo que devuelve `type(l).__name__` es un string y tu lo estás comparando con un Objeto (que es de diferente tipo en cada `if`), Lo correcto sería hacer `if type(l) == Coche`, de esta forma se compara que el tipo de la variable `l` sea igual a la clase. No recomiendo comparar el nombre de las clases ya que de formas muy raras puede ser manipulable. Pero si lo deseas puedes hacer `if type(l).__name__ == Coche.__name__`

Comment: @Christian algo no me cuadra del codigo.. cada clase no puede imprimir directamente su tipo en el metodo  `__str__`??? de esa forma, no hay if, solo llama a ese metodo para cada objeto... porque tampoco esta haciendo uso de eso...

Comment: @gbianchi sí, puede hacer eso y lo malo que no lo hace, estaba escribiendo una respuesta simplificando la función catalogar, pero me no había leído el código completo y había ignorado la implementación de `__str__`. Ahora escribo la respuesta con el código entero :D

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Como lo mencioné en mi comentario el error es por que comparas un string con un objeto. La solución sería comparar 2 string (los nombres) o comparar los tipo (objetos). Además, tu función catalogar se puede hacer más simple, dado que cada objeto implementa el método `__str__` y dentro de este imprime sus atributos entonces no hace falta volver a escribir el código que hace eso, es tan simple como imprimir el objeto

```py
def catalogar(lista):
    for elemento in lista:
        #verificamos que el tipo esté en la tupla
        if type(elemento) in (Coche, Camioneta, Bicicleta, Motocicleta):
            print(elemento)
        else: 
            print("Error al mostrar el catalogo del objeto {}.".format(elemento.__name__))
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque simplemente no haces:

```
class Vehiculo:
    """Esta clase la usaremos para crear las clases posteriores que nos pide el ejercicio.
    
    args
    - color
    - ruedas
    """
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        
    def __str__(self):
        return """ < {} >
        > COLOR: {}
        > RUEDAS: {}
        """.format(type(self).__name__,self.color,self.ruedas)
        
class Coche(Vehiculo):
    """Clase que hereda directamente de 'Vehiculo' e incluye nuevos atributos.
    
    args
    - color
    - ruedas
    - velocidad
    - cilindrada
    """
       
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
    
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        > VELOCIDAD: {}
        > CILINDRADA: {}
        """.format(self.velocidad,
                   self.cilindrada)

class Camioneta(Coche):
    """Subclase que hereda de la clase padre 'Coche'.Esta clase, ademas de incluir los atributos de
       las clases anteriores,obtinene un nuevo atributo que indica la instancia va cargada o no.
       
       args
       - color
       - ruedas
       - velocidad
       - cilindrada
       - carga
    """
        
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada,carga = False):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada)
        self.carga = carga
        
    def vaCargada(self):
        if self.carga == False:
            print("La camioneta no va cargada.")
        else:
            print("La camioneta va cargada.")
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.carga == True:
            return super().__str__() + """
            > CARGA: Camioneta cargada
            """
        else:
            return super().__str__() + """
        > CARGA: Camioneta vacia
            """

class Bicicleta(Vehiculo):
    """Clase que hereda directamente de 'Vehiculo',e incorpora un nuevo atributo aparte de
       los dos atributos iniciales.
       
       args
       - color
       - ruedas
       - tipo
       """
        
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,tipo):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas)
        self.tipo = tipo
    
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        > TIPO: {}
        """.format(self.tipo)

class Motocicleta(Bicicleta):
    """Subclase que hereda directamente de la clase padre 'Bicicleta', tomando sus atributos
       e incorporando dos nuevos
       
       args
       - color
       - ruedas
       - tipo
       - velocidad
       - cilindrada
       """
      
    def __init__(self,color,ruedas,tipo,velocidad,cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas,tipo)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
        
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        > VELOCIDAD: {}
        > CILINDRADA: {}
        """.format(self.velocidad,
                   self.cilindrada)
    
def catalogar(lista):
    for l in lista:
        print(l)
```

Es lo mismo lo único que saqué lo redundante

y al final:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    coche1 = Coche("Blanco",4,260,200)
    camioneta1 = Camioneta("Marron",4,200,160)
    bicicleta1 = Bicicleta("Azul",2,"BMX")
    motocicleta1 = Motocicleta("Negro",2,"carreras",300,280)
    listaVehiculos = [coche1,camioneta1,bicicleta1,motocicleta1]
    catalogar(listaVehiculos)
```

donde ya muestra lo que definiste en la función **str**